# Dismissing a company is not working properly

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

I mistakenly clicked the dismiss icon on a jobs ad and noticed that it didn't work as intended, the dismiss icon disappeared and the title became:

> Oops! Something went wrong. Don't worry, our best people are on it!

[image]

However, request's response seemed valid:

```
{
  "content": "<div>Okay, you won't see this company anymore.&nbsp;<a class=\"clc-dismiss-undo\"data-clc-click=\"https://clc.stackoverflow.com/click?an=AT0Awv8K_IHBNXXN1kgJvOtCRwIBEP7wngE7A-uoCrCwDIygFQ0UAB3AdO6KOUhhyj4BA7T9CwCcnOWUXvFU4_KT&cr=348172&ct=-4&sig=8VWiSaWrcRdkEQ\" data-clc-meta-target=\"-4\">Undo</a><span class=\"clc-spinner clc-hidden\"></span></div>"
}
```

**OS:** Windows 10

**Browser:** Chrome Version 73.0.3683.103 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Probably Windows :P Did you try clearing your cache?

Comment: Just tested on Windows 10 with same version of Chrome. Seems to be working normally. So not a blanket problem with the site.

Comment: @SteveE Were it a blanket problem, they probably would have fixed it within 24 hours.

Comment: @script47 is this still an issue for you? We weren't able to reproduce it.

Comment: @Des my bad, just saw this: https://gyazo.com/7772730338dc49adc912c497a6984efc - You can see the tooltip showing the starting of the '*Oops![...]*'. This was done just now.